# Flask-SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship on single table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to set up a many-to-many relationship using Flask-SQLAlchemy so that I can have a list of "related videos" for each entry in a Videos table.

```
class Videos(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False)

    related_videos = db.relationship("Videos", \
        secondary = "related_videos", \
        primaryjoin="id==related_videos.c.video_id", \
        secondaryjoin = "id==related_videos.c.related_id", \
        backref ="related_to")

    def __init__(self, title, ytid):
        self.title = title

related_videos = db.Table("related_videos", \
    db.Column("video_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Videos.id")), \
    db.Column("related_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Videos.id")))
```

When I try to add a new entry, for example with `example = Videos("foobar")` I get the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not determine relationship direction for primaryjoin condition 'related_videos.video_id = :video_id_1', on relationship Videos.related_videos.

I'm not sure why it isn't working - as far as I can tell, I'm doing pretty much the same thing as the SQLAlchemy documentation (though I'm probably wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two foreignKeys of the same name (Videos.id) in the "related_videos" table.

Shouldn't one be named "related.id"?

Also you named your relationship the same name as a whole table, I'm not sure if that is correct either.